# TypeError: global.moduleMerge is not a function

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

After I upgraded to nativescript 2.2.1 I get this error when running the application:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application com.tns.NativeScriptApplication: com.tns.NativeScriptException: 
Error calling module function 

TypeError: global.moduleMerge is not a function
File: "<unknown>, line: 1, column: 265

StackTrace: 
    Frame: function:'', file:'/data/data/org.nativescript.hw1/files/app/tns_modules/utils/utils.js', line: 3, column: 8
    Frame: function:'require', file:'', line: 1, column: 266
    Frame: function:'', file:'/data/data/org.nativescript.hw1/files/app/tns_modules/file-system/file-system-access.js', line: 2, column: 13
    Frame: function:'require', file:'', line: 1, column: 266
    Frame: function:'', file:'/data/data/org.nativescript.hw1/files/app/tns_modules/file-system/file-system.js', line: 1, column: 86
    Frame: function:'require', file:'', line: 1, column: 266
    Frame: function:'', file:'/data/data/org.nativescript.hw1/files/app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/file-system/ns-file-system.js', line: 2, column: 21
    Frame: function:'require', file:'', line: 1, column: 26
```

I have tried to delete both ./node_modules and ./platform folders in order to make sure everything is fresh but that does not help.

Here are my dependancies (from the package.json):

```
    "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/platform-server": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0-beta.2",
    "@angular/router-deprecated": "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "nativescript-angular": "next",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.5",
    "tns-core-modules": "2.2.1",
    "email-validator": "^1.0.4",
    "nativescript-social-share": "^1.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-traverse": "6.13.0",
    "babel-types": "6.13.0",
    "babylon": "6.9.0",
    "lazy": "1.0.11",
    "nativescript-dev-typescript": "^0.3.2",
    "typescript": "^1.8.10"
  }
```

Comment: Also delete the "lib" folder as it holds the native iOS libraries.

Comment: Just running for Android at the moment.

Comment: Maybe you are hitting this issue https://github.com/telerik/nativescript-ui-samples-angular/issues/3

Comment: Yes I think it is a similar issue. But when looking at the files in the apk-folder and looking at global I could see any problems there. Also think it is unclear how user giangdm got things to work.

Comment: I get this error when following the fix to problem described in issue 397 on nativescript-angular:
https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-angular/issues/397

Answer (score 0):

Following the advice from Alexander Vakrilov here [issue 393](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-angular/issues/393)
and making sure that the first import in main.ts is `import {nativeScriptBootstrap} from "nativescript-angular/application";` fixes the problem.